# Javascript Help Needed to Preserve String Value Location through Custom Sorting Script

Tags: javascript, string, variables, split, sorting

I have a string variable that is defined as the following:

`Jane's Account-123456789-Bob's Account-123456-Fred's Account-246802-Lily's Account-13579-Jim's Account-46748764-`

For the sake of this question let's say that is equal to `var value1;`

I am trying to take this string and run a query that will find a matching account number and then display the associated Account name.  To do this, I have started by splitting the variable into an array:

`var value2=value1.split("-");`

When I do this the sorting function reorders the list by increasing numbers and then alphabetical order.

`value2 = ,123456789,13579,246802,46748764,46748764,Bob's Account,Fred's Account,Jane's Account,Jim's Account,Lily's Account`

I would like to know how I can break the string out into an array and still maintain the order of the split materials.

This would be the desired output:

`,Jane's Account,123456789,Bob's Account,123456,Fred's Account,246802,Lily's Account,13579,Jim's Account,46748764`

Thanks.

Comment: What is the sorting function ?

Comment: I dont understand, can't you just do `value1.replace('-',',')`?

Comment: Your code already gives the desired output. Check out this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/kGMPq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if that string of data could be formatted any better.  Where is it coming from?  Can it not just be passed to you in JSON format?  That would be plan A.

Plan B is to parse it yourself, turn the structure into something like an array of objects:

```
var value1 = "Jane's Account-123456789-Bob's Account-123456-Fred's Account-246802-Lily's Account-13579-Jim's Account-46748764-";

// get rid of the last hyphen
value1 = value1.replace(/-$/, '');

// split up the input
var parts = value1.split('-');

// build the new structure
var accounts = [];
for (var i=0; i < parts.length; i+=2) {
    accounts.push({'name': parts[i], 'number': parts[i + 1]});
}

alert(JSON.stringify(accounts));

// sort accounts by name
accounts.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.name == b.name) return 0;
    if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
    return -1;
});

alert(JSON.stringify(accounts));
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eh6Dk/1/)